# Proper auth method against keystone ( openstack )

Tags: authentication, openstack

Should I directly query the API or rely on importing methods from the keystone client?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the python-keystoneclient bindings for initial authentication but for any query outside the scope of the keystoneclient API I simply referenced the auth_token and called to requests for direct API queries against the keystone ec2 url with the token in the header.

This worked well enough.  Keystone needs work.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on your requirements as to how you want to interact with keystone.

If you're querying the API directly then you're probably using curl in a bash script or from the command line. This can be particularly useful if you're working with bleeding edge keystone API code from trunk that doesn't even have methods in the keystone client yet.

If you're importing methods from the keystone client you're probably writing a python script or application. This is the better option if you're working with stable keystone code from a stable branch or package. The keystone client is just easier to work with rather than raw HTTP requests.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use the keystone client methods. The python-keystoneclient package has documentation on how to do this in the doc directory. For example, see [The client API](https://github.com/openstack/python-keystoneclient/blob/master/doc/source/using-api.rst).